# MongoDB - Unable to call 'GenerateNewId' method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb, mongodb-query

***Question Background:***

I've just started looking into using MongoDB with ASP.NET MVC and am having an issue when setting an Id to the 'Id' property of my model class.

***The Issue:***

The tutorial I'm using calls the `GenerateNewId()` method of the Mongo driver `ObjectId` class but I am unable to use this method, as it dosen't seem to exist - intellisense cant find it.

***The code:***

The model class:

```
 public class RealEstate
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { set; get; }
    public string Description { set; get; }
    public int NumberOfRoom { set; get; }
    public List<string> Address { set; get; }

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Double)]
    public decimal Price { set; get; }
}
```

Trying to set the ID:

```
var rental = new RealEstate();

**//Error:The 'GenerateId()' method dosent exist:**
rental.Id = new ObjectId.GenerateNewId.ToString();
```

I can set the Id as shown in the code below, ***but this sets it to all zeros*** :

```
 var rental = new RealEstate();

 rental.Id = new ObjectId().ToString();
```

**Can anyone tell me how to set this Id?**

Answer (score 2):

Incredibly embarrassing but I've just noticed that I've been trying to make an instance of the static class 'ObjectId'